# how to set href to outter website programatically?

Tags: html, css, href

I'm generating html page programatically.

I have an href with this src

```
"https:/www.w.com/editor/?lon=-72.382769&lat=41.324657"
```

however when i generate the html like this:

```
private Span getEditorSpan(CompleteRoutingResponseShort response) {
    Span span4 = new Span();
    for (int i = 0; i < response.alternatives.size(); i++) {
        String editorUrl = editorUrlGenerator
                .generateUrl(response.alternatives.get(i).response.results);

        A a3 = new A();
        a3.appendText("alt " + i);
        a3.setTitle(response.alternatives.get(i).alternative_regression_id);
        a3.setHref(editorUrl);

        span4.appendChild(ImmutableList.of(a3, new Span().appendText("&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp")));
    }
    return span4;
}
```

the result is an href that directs to:

```
"http://localhost:63342/https:/www.w.com/editor/?lon=-72.382769&lat=41.324657"
```

this is the resulted html:

```
<span><a title="358_0" href="https:/www.w.com/editor/?lon=-71.18612999999999&amp;lat=42.21286&amp;zoom=4&amp;segments=63385498,76487105,22543109,22503638,22527613,76599462,76599461,76599460">alt 0</a><span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></span>
```

how can I make the url direct outside my localhost domain?

this is my url builder:

```
    UriBuilder builder = UriBuilder
            .fromPath(Constants.EDITOR_BASE_URL)
            .scheme("https");

    builder.queryParam("lon", firstPath.x)
            .queryParam("lat", firstPath.y)
            .queryParam("zoom", 4)
            .queryParam("segments", segmentsInUrl);


    return builder.build().toString();
```

Comment: it's because you have only a single slash after http:

Comment: your `https:/` is wrong, it shoudl be `https://`, which explain why the browser fallback on a relative url instead of a full one, check your datasource

Comment: how can I chane my uri builder?

Comment: If you post your `editorUrlGenerator.generateUrl()` method we can try to help finding that single slash.

Comment: Does any of the answers solve your problem? If so, please select the right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The protocol set in your URL is `https:/` and not 'https://'. This causes the application to think it is a relative URL. Fix this problem and it shouldn't prepend the domain name `http://localhost:63342` afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to change my UriBuilder:

I have changed my UriBuilder

from this:

```
UriBuilder builder = UriBuilder
            .fromPath("www.w.com/editor/";)
            .scheme("https");

    builder.queryParam("lon", firstPath.x)
            .queryParam("lat", firstPath.y)
            .queryParam("zoom", 4)
            .queryParam("segments", segmentsInUrl);


return builder.build().toString();
```

to this:

```
    Path firstPath = results.get(0).path;

    UriBuilder builder = UriBuilder
            .fromUri("https://www.w.com/editor/")
            .queryParam("lon", firstPath.x)
            .queryParam("lat", firstPath.y)
            .queryParam("zoom", 4)
            .queryParam("segments", segmentsInUrl);


    return builder.build().toString();
}
```

Comment: Edit this into your question please. This will get flagged as 'comment on the question and not an answer'.